# How to successfully upgrade angular (from 6.0.9 to 7.1.4) and material from 6.3.2 to 7.2.0 (or latest version) with no dependencies errors?

Tags: angular, angular-material

I tried many times to upgrade the angular packages but this seems to be bottle neck every time.

Google does a lot of rapid changes and brings new versions (even after a day or two a new version is replaced).

Can anybody guide me properly? I tried different articles but I am still getting these errors while upgrading.

These are the guides I am following: [First](https://www.talkingdotnet.com/upgrade-angular-6-app-angular-7-visual-studio-2017/) [Second](https://update.angular.io/)

I executed these `ng` commands to upgrade my source code.

**1). `ng update @angular/cli @angular/core`**

... and the response is:

```
    ClientApp>ng update @angular/cli @angular/core
    Updating package.json with dependency @angular/forms @ "7.1.4" (was "6.0.9")...
    Updating package.json with dependency rxjs @ "6.3.3" (was "6.2.2")...
    Updating package.json with dependency @angular/language-service @ "7.1.4" (was "6.0.9")...
    Updating package.json with dependency @angular/common @ "7.1.4" (was "6.0.9")...
    Updating package.json with dependency @angular/router @ "7.1.4" (was "6.0.9")...
    Updating package.json with dependency @angular/animations @ "7.1.4" (was "6.0.9")...
    Updating package.json with dependency @angular/platform-browser-dynamic @ "7.1.4" (was "6.0.9")...
    Updating package.json with dependency @angular/compiler-cli @ "7.1.4" (was "6.0.9")...
    Updating package.json with dependency @angular/core @ "7.1.4" (was "6.0.9")...
    Updating package.json with dependency @angular/platform-browser @ "7.1.4" (was "6.0.9")...
    Updating package.json with dependency @angular/cli @ "7.1.4" (was "6.0.8")...
    Updating package.json with dependency typescript @ "3.1.6" (was "2.7.2")...
    Updating package.json with dependency @angular/compiler @ "7.1.4" (was "6.0.9")...
UPDATE package.json (2167 bytes)
npm WARN @angular/cdk@6.3.3 requires a peer of @angular/core@>=6.0.0-beta.0 <7.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @angular/cdk@6.3.3 requires a peer of @angular/common@>=6.0.0-beta.0 <7.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @angular/flex-layout@6.0.0-beta.16 requires a peer of @angular/core@^6.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @angular/flex-layout@6.0.0-beta.16 requires a peer of @angular/common@^6.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @angular/material@6.3.3 requires a peer of @angular/core@>=6.0.0-beta.0 <7.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @angular/material@6.3.3 requires a peer of @angular/common@>=6.0.0-beta.0 <7.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @ngtools/webpack@6.0.8 requires a peer of typescript@~2.4.0 || ~2.5.0 || ~2.6.0 || ~2.7.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN codelyzer@4.2.1 requires a peer of @angular/compiler@>=2.3.1 <7.0.0 || >6.0.0-beta <7.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN codelyzer@4.2.1 requires a peer of @angular/core@>=2.3.1 <7.0.0 || >6.0.0-beta <7.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN codelyzer@4.2.1 requires a peer of @angular/platform-browser-dynamic@>=2.3.1 <7.0.0 || >6.0.0-beta <7.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN codelyzer@4.2.1 requires a peer of @angular/platform-browser@>=2.3.1 <7.0.0 || >6.0.0-beta <7.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN codelyzer@4.2.1 requires a peer of @angular/common@>=2.3.1 <7.0.0 || >6.0.0-beta <7.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN ngx-toasta@0.1.0 requires a peer of @angular/common@^6.0.0-rc.0 || ^6.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN ngx-toasta@0.1.0 requires a peer of @angular/core@^6.0.0-rc.0 || ^6.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.4 (node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.4: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})

added 123 packages from 82 contributors, removed 8 packages, updated 17 packages, moved 2 packages and audited 23046 packages in 76.044s
found 21 vulnerabilities (9 low, 4 moderate, 8 high)
  run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details
Invalid rule result: Function().
```

-- =====================================================

After the first command has completed, I executed this command:

**2). `ng update @angular/material`**

... and I got the following response back on command prompt:

```
ClientApp>ng update @angular/material
              Package "@angular/flex-layout" has an incompatible peer dependency to "@angular/cdk" (requires "^6.0.0", would install "7.2.0").
```

Incompatible peer dependencies found. See above.

========================================================================

After your mentioned commands, I have executed

1). **npm i @angular/flex-layout@7.0.0-beta.22 --save**

and the response is below:

```
ClientApp>npm i @angular/flex-layout@7.0.0-beta.22 --save
```

npm WARN @angular/cdk@6.3.3 requires a peer of @angular/core@>=6.0.0-beta.0 <7.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @angular/cdk@6.3.3 requires a peer of @angular/common@>=6.0.0-beta.0 <7.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @angular/material@6.3.3 requires a peer of @angular/core@>=6.0.0-beta.0 <7.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @angular/material@6.3.3 requires a peer of @angular/common@>=6.0.0-beta.0 <7.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @ngtools/webpack@6.0.8 requires a peer of typescript@~2.4.0 || ~2.5.0 || ~2.6.0 || ~2.7.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN codelyzer@4.2.1 requires a peer of @angular/compiler@>=2.3.1 <7.0.0 || >6.0.0-beta <7.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN codelyzer@4.2.1 requires a peer of @angular/core@>=2.3.1 <7.0.0 || >6.0.0-beta <7.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN codelyzer@4.2.1 requires a peer of @angular/platform-browser-dynamic@>=2.3.1 <7.0.0 || >6.0.0-beta <7.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN codelyzer@4.2.1 requires a peer of @angular/platform-browser@>=2.3.1 <7.0.0 || >6.0.0-beta <7.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN codelyzer@4.2.1 requires a peer of @angular/common@>=2.3.1 <7.0.0 || >6.0.0-beta <7.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN ngx-toasta@0.1.0 requires a peer of @angular/common@^6.0.0-rc.0 || ^6.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN ngx-toasta@0.1.0 requires a peer of @angular/core@^6.0.0-rc.0 || ^6.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @angular/flex-layout@7.0.0-beta.22 requires a peer of @angular/cdk@^7.0.0-rc.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.4 (node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.4: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})

- @angular/flex-layout@7.0.0-beta.22
  updated 1 package in 221.832s

===================================================================

After flex-layout npm package command,

**2). ng update @angular/material**

and the response is :

```
    ClientApp>ng update @angular/material
    Updating package.json with dependency @angular/cdk @ "7.2.0" (was "6.3.3")...
    Updating package.json with dependency @angular/material @ "7.2.0" (was "6.3.3")...
UPDATE package.json (2167 bytes)
npm WARN @ngtools/webpack@6.0.8 requires a peer of typescript@~2.4.0 || ~2.5.0 || ~2.6.0 || ~2.7.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN codelyzer@4.2.1 requires a peer of @angular/compiler@>=2.3.1 <7.0.0 || >6.0.0-beta <7.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN codelyzer@4.2.1 requires a peer of @angular/core@>=2.3.1 <7.0.0 || >6.0.0-beta <7.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN codelyzer@4.2.1 requires a peer of @angular/platform-browser-dynamic@>=2.3.1 <7.0.0 || >6.0.0-beta <7.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN codelyzer@4.2.1 requires a peer of @angular/platform-browser@>=2.3.1 <7.0.0 || >6.0.0-beta <7.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN codelyzer@4.2.1 requires a peer of @angular/common@>=2.3.1 <7.0.0 || >6.0.0-beta <7.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN ngx-toasta@0.1.0 requires a peer of @angular/common@^6.0.0-rc.0 || ^6.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN ngx-toasta@0.1.0 requires a peer of @angular/core@^6.0.0-rc.0 || ^6.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.4 (node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.4: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})

added 1 package from 1 contributor, removed 1 package, updated 2 packages and audited 23046 packages in 24.069s
found 21 vulnerabilities (9 low, 4 moderate, 8 high)
  run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have a public repo for this so it can be reproduced ?

Although a quick check revelaled , you should update `@angular/flex-layout` to `7.0.0-beta.22`

This to remove the incompatible warnings//errors

`npm i @angular/flex-layout@7.0.0-beta.22 --save`

This suggestion is based on the above `console` output and the commands. It seems some package is holding `angular/cdk@6.x`, probably `@angular/flex-layout`. I will probably update that before running material update.

Comment: please see the command responses above in the main post. I am adding the command s and responses  above

Comment: @maifs I made the suggestions based on the above `console` output and the commands. I seems some package is holding `angular/cdk@6.x`, probably `@angular/flex-layout`. I will probably update that before running material update.

Comment: yes those errors have been gone. thank you if you can reply to the above package then it 'll be appreciated.

Comment: Which package ? I'll add this to the answer, please accept if it helped

Comment: thank you Ankesh.  Shoul i upgrade these packages ?

@ngtools/webpack@6.0.8
codelyzer@4.2.1
ngx-toasta@0.1.0

and for 
optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.4 (node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.4: wa

Comment: @ngtools/webpack and codelyzer can be upgraded (you can see the version by creating a dummy project with latest `ng-cli`). leave `fs-events` as is :)

Comment: I have checked both have the upgraded versions but this package doesn't have ngx-toasta@0.1.0 any latest version

Comment: I think then you are out of luck :) . Probably change the package ?